# How do I rename a calculated column using SharePoint 2010 list webservices

Tags: web-services, calculated-column, rename, display-name

I'm having trouble figuring out how to rename a calculated column. The below code creates the 3 fields, and renames the first two but it won't rename the 3rd one.

```
<UpdateList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listName>listName</listName>';
    <newFields>
        <Fields>
            <Method ID="1">
                <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="nDingoMan" />
            </Method>
            <Method ID="2">
                <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="nBingoMan" />
            </Method>
            <Method ID="3">
                <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="nDingoBingoMan" ResultType="Text">
                    <Formula>=nDingoMan&amp;&quot;-&quot;&amp;nBingoMan</Formula>
                    <FieldRefs>
                        <FieldRef Name="nDingoMan"/>
                        <FieldRef Name="nBingoMan"/>
                    </FieldRefs>
                </Field>
            </Method>
        </Fields>
    </newFields>
    <updateFields>
        <Fields>
            <Method ID="4">
                <Field Type="Text" Name="nDingoMan" DisplayName="dingo man" />
            </Method>
            <Method ID="5">
                <Field Type="Text" Name="nBingoMan" DisplayName="bingo man" />
            </Method>
            <Method ID="6">
                <Field Type="Calculated" Name="nDingoBingoMan" DisplayName="dingo bingo man" />
            </Method>
        </Fields>
    </updateFields>
</UpdateList>
```

I've tried doing the newFields and updateFields in the same call and in different calls but no dice.

```
<UpdateList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listName>listName</listName>';
    <updateFields>
        <Fields>
            <Method ID="1">
                <Field Type="Calculated" Name="nDingoBingoMan" DisplayName="dingo bingo man" />
            </Method>
        </Fields>
    </updateFields>
</UpdateList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<Method ID="6">
    <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="dingo bingo man" Name="nDingoBingoMan"  ResultType="Text" ReadOnly="TRUE">
        <Formula>=nDingoMan&amp;&quot;-&quot;&amp;nBingoMan</Formula>
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef Name="nDingoMan"/>
            <FieldRef Name="nBingoMan"/>
        </FieldRefs>
    </Field>
</Method>
```

Comment: Thanks! In that case, is it possible in the newFields to create the CC with minimum information and then do the rest in the updateFields? That way I wouldn't have to provide the formula and fieldref information twice?

Comment: You need to provide Type, Formula, DisplayName and ResultType in create.